# Coordinate multiple view animations on exit transition in android

Tags: c#, android, animation, material-design, transition

I am trying to figure out how to handle animating multiple views when moving between activities.  It seems like android only really allows you animate the activity itself when leaving it.  How would I go about implementing a slide_out_top animation on one view and a slide_out_bottom on another view in the same activity as an exit transition?

Comment: Have you tried using an animation method on the views just before you start the activity transition?

Comment: I suggest reading this tutorial first https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50#.g2xuirbdy and then try implementing it. BUt first try and understand the concept

Answer (score 0):

Call the 
    `view1.animate().translateY(-..).setDuration(..).start()` 
and 
    `view2.animate.translateY(+..).setDuration(..).start()` in `onStop()`. If you don't like the effect, try calling those before calling `startActivity(..)`.